# python - repositioning my legend using loc

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, legend

this is the output of my code

[image]

as you can see both legends 'pl' and 'ppl' are overlapping at the top right. How do I get one of them to move to top left.
I tried searching for ans, and used "loc" to fix the issue, somehow I continue getting error. Can someone help please?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.set_xlabel('Date')
ax1.set_ylabel('percent change / 100')
dd = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,(30,2)),columns=['pl','ppl'])
dd['pl'].plot(ax=ax1,legend=True)
dd['ppl'].plot(ax=ax2, style=['g--', 'b--', 'r--'],legend=True)

ax2.set_ylabel('difference')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to call `legend` on `plot` and position the legend accordingly. Please see below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.set_xlabel('Date')
ax1.set_ylabel('percent change / 100')
dd = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,(30,2)),columns=['pl','ppl'])

dd['pl'].plot(ax=ax1, legend=True).legend(loc='center left',bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5))
dd['ppl'].plot(ax=ax2, style=['g--', 'b--', 'r--'],legend=True).legend(loc='upper right')
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps plot directly with matplotlib instead of using `DataFrame.plot`:

```
ax1.plot(dd['pl'], label='pl')
ax1.legend(loc='upper left')
ax2.plot(dd['ppl'], ls='--', c='g', label='ppl')
ax2.legend(loc='upper right')
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create the legend in several ways:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.set_xlabel("Date")
ax1.set_ylabel("percent change / 100")
dd = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, (30, 2)), columns=["pl", "ppl"])
dd["pl"].plot(ax=ax1)
dd["ppl"].plot(ax=ax2, style=["g--", "b--", "r--"])

# # two separate legends
# ax1.legend()
# ax2.legend(loc="upper left")

# # a single legend for the whole fig
# fig.legend(loc="upper right")

# # a single legend for the axis
# get the lines in the axis
lines1 = ax1.lines
lines2 = ax2.lines
all_lines = lines1 + lines2
# get the label for each line
all_labels = [lin.get_label() for lin in all_lines]
# place the legend
ax1.legend(all_lines, all_labels, loc="upper left")

ax2.set_ylabel("difference")
plt.show()
```

The last one I left uncommented creates a single legend inside the ax, with both lines listed.

Cheers!